# python:"\" in str a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

```
   if "\\" in item["message"]:
       item["message"] = str(item["message"]).replace("\\", "\\\\").encode("utf-8")
```

write the program, there are many "\" in item['message'], therefore, when trying to insert this item in mysql table, it errors, I try to deal with the "\" in item["message"], so I write the program above,

when it run,it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py", line 237, in <module>
    group_download.group_feed_storage(FB_access_token,group_id,group_name)
  File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\group_download.py", line 116, in group_feed_storage
    mysql_manage().group_feed_db_manage(type,group,name,feed)
  File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\database_manage.py", line 95, in group_feed_db_manage
    if "\\" in item["message"]:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could you please help me for that

Comment: what is `type(item["message"])`?

Answer (score 0):

`item['message']` is a bytes-like object, so it may contain certain sequences of bytes, but won't contain substrings. Search for a bytes-like object:

```
if b"\\" in item["message"]:
   ^
```

Comment: I have modified the program as you said,but it errors again,please see my answer as follows

Comment: @bin - That is a different error not described anywhere in your question. If you are encountering a new problem that you cannot solve with extensive research, ask a new question. Don't post updates to your question as an answer.